# fetching a text file in react typescript is returning the html page as a response?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add a text file into my react app and by using fetch the problem is instead of getting the text I am getting my html page as a response an idea how to implement this the right way? I have big text files that is needed to keep locally and then inject them into my app on load instead of keeping them in my code since they are too big.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('./src/text.txt').then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      response.text().then(function (text) {
         console.log(text);
        setText(text)
      });
    });
    
  }, []);
  
  
  
  
  // Console.log(Text)
  
  <head>
  <!-- Icons to support Material Design -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
</head>
```